# Views filter by date

Tags: 8, datetime

I I'm trying to filter my view by a date filter in Drupal 8. I have a content type with a date field (without time).

I have a a range filter. When I filter >= 01-12-2017 (dd-mm-yyyy) till <= 31-12-2017. Agenda items on 30 nov will show.

When I filter on >= 01-11-2017 and <= 30-11-2017 these agenda items won't show? Any idea what is going wrong. It looks like there is a day difference...or the equal to options is not working.

Any idea what to dot with this problem?

Comment: It sounds like you may be running into https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2627512

Comment: At looked at the patches but part of the code is already in the module some parts aren't is it safe to patch everything that is not the module already?